# Put header text beside navigation bar

Tags: html, css

Started on a project that will be used for educational purposes as it requires html,css and php which
I am still learning! I want to know how can I position my H4 so it lines up with the navigation text.
Is there a better way of doing this? `http://66.172.10.179/resolver/`

CSS:

```
/* Body */
body {
    background-color: #FF5930;
}

/* Navigation bar */

header {
    background-color: #FF4719;
}

nav h2 a{
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}

nav h2 a:hover{
    color: gray;
    text-decoration: none;
}


nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <h2 class="header-text"><a href="index.php">Skype Resolver</a></h2>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php">Resolver</a></li>
            <li><a href="blacklist.php">Blacklisting</a></li>
            <li><a href="purchase.php">Purchase API</a></li>
            <li><a href="dtools.php">Domain tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="stools.php">Spam tools</a></li>
            <li><a href="mtools.php">Misc tools</a></li>
        </ul>                           
    </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Add `margin` and `padding` to `nav ul`:

```
nav ul {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Change `nav ul li` to this:

```
nav ul li {
    display: inline;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6pbM7/2)**